# Why is Google Analytics In-Page Analytics telling me that the tracking code isn't installed when it clearly is?

Tags: wordpress, google-analytics

I see this problem pop up in a lot of places and asking on Google's product support forums was no help at all, so I turn to you guys. My client has asked me to look into this problem with their In-Page Analytics reporting which turns up the errors:

- Your site doesn't load ga.js from Google. If you host the Google
  tracking code on your own servers, it isn't updated automatically and
  can miss important changes.
- We didn't find a tracking snippet on your site. In-Page Analytics
  cannot load. Please make sure you have tracking installed correctly.
  If your snippet is included in a separate JavaScript file, you'll
  have to manually check it is being loaded correctly.

Both of these statements are false. To ensure that it wasn't my original setup that was the problem I installed Yoast's GA plugin (it's a wordpress site) and I still get this error. I've also confirmed that the tracking ID is correct. All other metrics are being reported in GA. This in-page section, however, is the problem.

This is the website, by the way. Any help you have to offer would be greatly appreciated.

http://stoppredatorygambling.org/

Answer (score 0):

How long has it been since the first hit to the property/view?  In my experience it takes anywhere from several hours to up to 2 days for that message to go away.